# How do I create a upload button on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload

I would like to know how I can create an upload button on a SharePoint page so a user is able to click on the upload button and upload a document. Like this one:
[image]

Comment: I have similar question however i have couple of folders created in library. I want to place document in that folder.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this old thread. Is it possible to "pre-add" the destination folder (document set), because my choose folder button does not work properly
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHf3d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHf3d.png) When I click there a new window pops up but I cannot choose anything
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzd01.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzd01.png) Yes, it shows the right root destination, but I see no document (set) under this. When I _first_ write the Folder manually in there
[![enter image descriptio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The upload form for a particular library can be accessed from

```
http://site/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={ID to the library}
```

You can get the `ID` by e.g. going to the Document Library Settings, and the URL should end with `List=<ID>`. Note, that if the URL starts with `%7B` and ends with `%7D`, those are decoded to `{` and `}` respectively, meaning you don't have to add the braces to the URL.

When you have your upload URL, you can link it to your desired element such as an image or a text for an upload.
[image]

Comment: could you give me a example please :)

Comment: @AY_91 added a screencap for an example.

Comment: I found it before you screenshot :P :P :P

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online:

- Go to Library Settings.
- Copy the URL and change "listedit" to "upload"

From:
https://site/_layouts/15/**listedit**.aspx?List=%7B370046a4-3a68-4cfd-9866-a8dbe807dc0f%7D

To:
https://site/_layouts/15/**upload**.aspx?List=%7B370046a4-3a68-4cfd-9866-a8dbe807dc0f%7D

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SharePoint Online, remember to add "15" to the URL prior to Upload. Example: //site/15/Upload=

Comment: Where and Why??